# Is there a file size limit transferring files to an Ubuntu box via SMB from Windows 10?

Tags: samba, shared-folders, transfer, smb

I am trying to move my media collection from windows 10 to an Ubuntu box via smb and I keep getting an error saying: **"There is not enough space on  you need an additional X gb to transfer these files."** Any files under 3gb in size works fine.

Some additional information - I'm transferring them into a ZFS pool with plenty of space.

```
scott@emby:~$ df -h  
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
udev                2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev  
tmpfs               597M  9.0M  588M   2% /run  
/dev/sda1            19G  4.4G   14G  25% /  
tmpfs               3.0G  180K  3.0G   1% /dev/shm  
tmpfs               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock  
tmpfs               3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
**mediapool/HomeVids  6.7T     0  6.7T   0% /mnt/zfs/HomeVids  
mediapool/Movies    7.1T  363G  6.7T   6% /mnt/zfs/Movies  
mediapool/TV        6.7T     0  6.7T   0% /mnt/zfs/TV**  
tmpfs               597M   60K  597M   1% /run/user/1000  
tmpfs               597M     0  597M   0% /run/user/121  
**mediapool/Anime     6.7T   11G  6.7T   1% /mnt/zfs/Anime**
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses a temporary location to transfer files and so does Ubuntu, Please check the windows temporary folder location and the /tmp directory on the ubuntu box. Try to free up some space and retry the operation.

Comment: This did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping /mnt/zfs/, mapping each individual dataset (mediapool/Movies) directly (/mnt/zfs/Movies) allowed me to transfer any amount.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a 2.5 GB space limit when transferring files through copy paste or drag into a remote desktop connection window. To move larger file sizes share the folder on windows and access it through ubuntu to get your files.